# Customize a view handle POST and DELETE method in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created a View that can handle POST and DELETE method

```
class MyView(APIView): 
    def valid_method(self,data):
        method = self.request.method 
        if method == 'POST':           
            ser = self.PostSerializer(data=data)       
        elif method == 'DELETE':           
            ser = self.DeleteSerializer(data=data)        
        else:           
            raise MethodValidationError(errormessage)       
        return ser       
    def post(self, request):       
        ser = self.valid_method(dara = request.data)        
        other code    
    def delete(self, request):       
        ser = self.valid_method(dara = request.data)
        other code
```

Is there any better way to implement MyView? Should I create a new base view?  Or is there any simple way to define the legal HTTP method in APIView?

Answer (score 0):

Use [GenericAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) (inherits from APIView), which provides methods such as `get_serializer_class`, where you can implement the logic in the method `valid_method`.

**Example**:

```
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView


class CustomGenericAPIView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = None

    def get_serializer_class(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request_method = self.request.method
        if request_method == "POST":
            return self.PostSerializer
        elif request_method == "DELETE":
            return self.DeleteSerializer
        else:
            return super().get_serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        # rest of the code
```

Comment: in the `DELETE` case should be `elif request_method == "DELETE"` not `elif request.method == "DELETE"`